# how to avoid await multiple functions in Node js?

Tags: node.js

actually i am using node.js api for my mobile application, once i am calling dashboard api there have lots of await functions that taking time to execute. so response time of that api is more then 12 sec ,here are my functions under my dashboard api can you suggest the way so we can increased my api response .

```
await globalVar.data.podBasicData(pod_id); 
await globalVar.data.podSameAdminData(pod_id); 
 await globalVar.data.podAdministratorData(pod_id); 
 await globalVar.data.podGaurantorsData(pod_id);
```

here more then 10 functions can you suggest. my how improved my api response

Comment: Why don't you await for all of them in parallel? `await Promise.all([globalVar.data...`

Comment: but how to get  response of the functions in different -2 variable becouse each functions given different type of result  for example   PodinformationData = await globalVar.data.podBasicData(pod_id);   can you give me example and reference please

Comment: var allresponsevariable = await Promise.all([globalVar.data.....all functions]) here how to get all functions response in single variable ?

Comment: @slebetman can you give me example please ? and explain more ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Promise.all` and an array destructuring to execute all functions in parallel and  to get each returned result to its respective variable:

```js
const [basicData, sameAdminData, AdministratorData, GaurantorsData] = await Promise.all([
  globalVar.data.podBasicData(pod_id),
  globalVar.data.podSameAdminData(pod_id),
  globalVar.data.podAdministratorData(pod_id),
  globalVar.data.podGaurantorsData(pod_id)]);
```

Comment: But once i have added all functions its give me empty return its not wait for execution just running next by next  functions not waiting for execution , means some functions giving value and some are not ?

Comment: Means not waiting for queries ?

Comment: Look at functions closely. Maybe somewhere you forgot `await`

Comment: i am using something like this see given below

Comment: Promise.all([ await globalVar.data.podBasicData(pod_id) ,
            await globalVar.data.podAdministratorData(pod_id)],
            await globalVar.data.podGaurantorsData(pod_id),
            await globalVar.data.podHashtagData(pod_id),
            await globalVar.data.podReturnData(pod_id),
            await globalVar.data.podParticipentsData(pod_id),
            await globalVar.data.podReturnFullData(pod_id),
            await globalVar.data.podReturnDueInData(pod_id),
    
      ).then((values) => { //here all results });

Comment: Even try await before promise.all like this : await Promise.all( [ await globalVar.data.podBasicData(pod_id) , await globalVar.data.podAdministratorData(pod_id)], await globalVar.data.podGaurantorsData(pod_id), await..........

Comment: `await` should be only before `Promise.all` and not before each its argument because it's useless (all functions will be finished before calling Promise.all)